# element.set_value not working in python appium for fill the application form

Tags: appium, python-appium

I am trying to fill the data like name, email, and other details on android app using python appium client getting below error.
**Appium server version -1.4.16.1
python appium client = 0.22 and 0.24**
getting below error not getting ant resolution.

```
    element.set_value('Test_Uder')
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\appium\webdriver\webelement.py", line 123, in set_value
    self._execute(Command.SET_IMMEDIATE_VALUE, data)
  File "D:\vikas_python_venv\my_appium\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.7.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 501, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "D:\vikas_python_venv\my_appium\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.7.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 29, in check_response
    raise wde
```

> WebDriverException: Message: Not yet implemented. Please help us:
>   http://appium.io/get-involved.html

Answer (score 0):

did you try using "send_keys" instead?

Something like this:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', 
desired_caps)

self.driver.find_element_by_id(          
'com.matchbook.client:id/editTextUsername').send_keys("username_here")
```

where "com.matchbook.client" is your package name, you can find element ID  (com.matchbook.client:id/editTextUsername) using Appium Inspector which is included in Appium desktop app.